# C++ template function associate parameter type with integer

Tags: c++, templates

I'm developing a library in C++ (17) for a machine for the CAN bus. I have different devices that I want to address, which have different functions. To make it easy to use, I use enum classes for the different devices, like this:

```
enum class WaterPump{
    On,
    Off
};

enum class Lift{
    Up,
    Down,
    Stop
};
```

Now I want a template function which sends the value of the enum class together with a specific address for the device:

```
template <typename T> send(T msg){
    uint32_t can_address = magic_function(msg); //This should return e.g. 0xF1 for type WaterPump //and 0xF2 for Lift
    send_can(can_address, (uint8_t) msg);
}
```

The idea is that the user can do this:

```
send(WaterPump::On); //Will call send_can(0xF1, 0);
send(Lift::Down); //Will call send_can(0xF2, 2);
```

Of course there are many possible solutions for this. One would be to make one enum containing all commands and a second enum for the device type. However, since I have a lot of devices, this would reduce clarity badly. One of the main reason why I want it to do with these enum classes is that you can type 'WaterPump::' and with the code completion, you see all possible commands.

I simplified my code a lot here. The whole thing is organized as a interface. There are other interfaces for other buses like I2C etc. So making an Class WaterPump with functions on() etc. is not the solution Im looking for.

Currently I use function overloading (without templates) and make a function for every device. However, this is quite cumbersome and confusing.

I'm searching for a solution where I have some kind of compact lookup table. Somehow like this:

```
#define TYPE_WATERPUMP 0xF1
#define TYPE_LIFT 0xF2
```

I thought about doing something with std::is_same, but I don't see yet how to get this in a compact form.

Can you think of an elegant way to do this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

template variable seems to do the job:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr uint32_t can_address = [](){ throw "Should be specialized"; }();

template <> constexpr uint32_t can_address<WaterPump> = 0xF1;
template <> constexpr uint32_t can_address<Lift> = 0xF2;


template <typename T> send(T msg){
    send_can(can_address<T>, (uint8_t) msg);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KdnM73eE7)

Comment: Awesome, that looks exactly like what I was looking for! Thanks! Its always amazing what C++ offers and I never heard off ^^

Comment: OK, now a tricky follow up: On the receiver side, you get the address as uint32_t. How could you now convert the message in the correct enum class type? The best would be something without redundancy, where the addresses are only defined once.

Comment: What I think is something like `template <typename ... Ts>const std::map<std::uint32_t, std::variant<Tag<Ts>...>>> addr_to_enum_impl = {{can_address<Ts>, Tag<Ts>{}}...}; const auto& addr_to_enum = addr_to_enum_impl<WaterPump, Lift>;`.