# C++ virtual template function best workaround

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions, policy-based-design

I have a class ComInterface which has a overloaded function send. This function is overloaded for many different enum class types.

```
class ComInterface{
public:
    virtual void send(MotorCommand cmd);
    virtual void send(ValveCommand cmd);
    virtual void send(ThrottleCommand cmd);
};
```

Then I have a derrived class CanCom

```
class CanCom: public ComInterface{
public:
    void send(uint32_t CanID, uint8_t cmd);
    virtual void send(MotorCommand cmd){
        send(1, (uint8_t) cmd); //1 is the Motor specific address
    }
    virtual void send(ValveCommand cmd){
        send(2, (uint8_t) cmd); //2 is the Valve specific address
    }
    virtual void send(ThrottleCommand cmd){
        send(3, (uint8_t) cmd); 
    }
};
```

This is the code so far. Since I have many of these enum classes (like MotorCommand), I would prefer to use a template. Something like:

```
class ComInterface{
public:
    template <typename T>
    virtual void send(T cmd);
};
```

The specific address would be then inserted with a template variable, as proposed here [C++ template function associate parameter type with integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77114319/c-template-function-associate-parameter-type-with-integer)
So something like [as proposed from Jarod42 in the linked question]

```
template <typename T>
constexpr uint32_t can_address = [](){ throw "Should be specialized"; }();
template <> constexpr uint32_t can_address<MotorCommand> = 1;
template <> constexpr uint32_t can_address<ValveCommand> = 2;
template <> constexpr uint32_t can_address<ThrottleCommand> = 3;


template <typename T> send(T cmd){
    send(can_address<T>, (uint8_t) msg);
}
```

But now I have the problem that I can't use templates AND virtual functions. After some research, I think the best way to resolve that is by using policy based design. So ComInterface is a template class and there is something like a CanImplementation class that is passed as a template parameter. Unfortunatley, this would mean that the type of ComInterface would have to be adaptet at every place it is used, which is not possible in my case.

My next idea was to have a new class "TypeToIDConverter", which converts the type to a ID. But then this class would have to be derived again to "TypeToCanIDConverter", and again, since it would have to be virtual, no templates could be used. I thought about using a normal override, and then convert the base type converter which would be stored in ComInterface to the derived class with a static_cast. However, Im not sure this will work, and it would be a ugly solution for sure!

Other ideas I found is type errasure and the visitor principle. However, Im not sure how I would use them here.

Is there a elegant solution for this? Something that I don't have to write a send function for every enum class type, but also keeps the Interface general and leaves room for new implementations for other protocols (like a LinCom or a I2CCom)?

Thank you a lot in advance! This problem bricks my head for days already...

Comment: Make `void send(uint32_t CanID, uint8_t cmd);` the virtual function in `ComInterface`, and have non-virtual function template forward to it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Im not sure if I get you correctly. This would mean that the part which converts the type to the CanID is fixed in the ComInterface, right? Unfortunatley, this is not a option, since the ID must be also specific for the communication protocol, e.g. CanCom has different IDs than LinCom.

Comment: `virtual void send(CommandType command_type, int command_id)` where `command_type` is not directly tied to addresses. Implementations would map the type to address as they see fit.

Comment: You could also use `std::variant` will all the enums.

Comment: What @IgorTandetnik means is `struct ComInterface { virtual void send(uint32_t, uint8_t); template<typename T> void send(T cmd) { send(can_address<T>, (uint8_t) cmd); } };`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Interesting idea, Thanks! That would improve the code for sure. The extra table that must be created brings a bit redundancy. Its a good solution, but one without a extra table would even be greater.

Comment: Your original code in effect has an extra table baked into `ComInterface` and every implementation class - namely, the vtable. You are just making it explicit. The mapping has to live *somewhere*.

Comment: @JerryCoffin There are no virtual functions in your answer? I thought the whole point of `ComInterface` was that it was meant to be used polymorphically.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The OP mentions `LinCom` and `I2CCom` classes that would derive from `ComInterface` just like `CanCom`. But that would assign different addresses to various command types than `CanCom` does (this last part is from the second comment: "the ID must be also specific for the communication protocol, e.g. `CanCom` has different IDs than `LinCom`" So I imagine a usage pattern like `ComInterface* protocol = ObtainProtocol(); protocol->send(Valve::Open);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Oops, you're right. I somehow missed that.

Comment: I am not quite sure the limitation. "I can't use templates AND virtual functions" but you want to use polymorphism which depends on vtable? What is your use case? If use case is `template<typename T> int sendFoo(T& instance){ instance.send("foo"); }`, the polymorphism isn't required. Just ensure you have the same function signature s across classes. Or... static polymorphism.. CRTP?

Comment: @LouisGo Not sure if I understand you correctly. I will have a interface where something like `ComInterface* com = new CanInterface` will happen (not exactly this, but a base class pointer will hold the derived class and this will not be avoidable. Then I want to `com->send(motor_cmd)` where `motor_cmd` is of type `MotorCommand`, and the send method of the derived class must be called. Since I can't avoid the base class pointer nor that the derived class method is called, I don't see any other possibilities than virtual. I you have a idea, could you make an example?

Comment: Oh I didn't walkthrough all the comments. Please update your question with the use case in your comment which requires runtime polymorphism.